# How to get the value of the transaction?

Tags: transactions, web3.py, python, blocks, raw-transaction

I am using web3.py but I need help to know the value of the transaction sent.
I know that the information is stored in the input but how do I parse the string. I know nothing about ABI.
Here is the `tx_hash = 0xb6a594e6e9579d76870d54618b8df25e6662a200f1d2f3c9e27f506e851fa092`
and here is the input: `0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000453a0961ed6badd98fc396b01ab9b5939d9e27f1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a`

How do I get the value of the transaction in a simple value ?

Comment: What is `the value of the transaction`?

Comment: @goodvibration The value is 0 because I transferred tokens and not ether. I need to get the amount of erc20 tokens sent

Comment: So your notion of "value" is incorrect here. The only way to interpret "value of a transaction" is as the amount of wei-ether passed to the destination address (whether this address is an externally-owned account or a contract). You're asking about the value of a parameter passed to a function in a contract. So this is how you should ask the question - how can I tell the value of parameter "x" passed to function "y", using the transaction hash? - you can't. But you can check the `balanceOf` your account (or the `totalSupply` of the contract) before and after the transaction, and figure it out.

Comment: Alternatively, there should be a `Transfer` event in the logs of the transaction receipt (which you can obtain using the transaction hash).

Comment: @goodvibration Sorry for the misunderstanding, I now tried to do: `w.eth.getTransactionReceipt('0xe95730480647c4298ec0e2376f619f7425d9e4cf4b1c7ba0415b1a8a81b54a21')` and if I take the value in the data, and do `int('0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000050',0)` I see that I get the correct value. Is this approach correct ?

Comment: Have you transferred `0x50` wei of your token? It should typically appear in the receipt logs (assuming that the function emits an event, which at least in the case of openzeppelin's implementation of ERC20, it does).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## New Answer (Based on comment)

To get the value of ERC20 tokens being transferred, you need to parse the input data of the transaction.

[Per the standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md), the `transfer` function looks as follows:

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)
```

This means that you must look for the final parameter in the input data. An example transaction can be seen [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb5f2ffa5e1d79e7cf5bee4892f75303db227554c322fa32c1e97026915b740a8). In this example, the input data is as follows:

> 0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000dfbc84ccac430f2c0455c437adf417095d7ad68e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000158b5ff8fb42b95000

`0xa9059cbb`

This is the hash of the method signature.

`000000000000000000000000dfbc84ccac430f2c0455c437adf417095d7ad68e`

This is the address where the tokens are being sent.

`0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000158b5ff8fb42b95000`

**This is the amount (in Hex) and is the value you are looking for.** In this example, this comes out to 397.424645 tokens.

---

## Original Answer

The `value` of the transaction is actually not in the `input` data, but rather in its own `value` field. If you know the hash, you can get the value.

```
>>> tx_data = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
>>> print(tx_data["value"])
1000000000000000000
```

If you get the transaction receipt, the `value` field will be included in the output. That is the amount of Wei sent in the transaction.

Comment: The problem is when transferring erc20 tokens, I need to know how many tokens I have transferred. When doing as you told me to do, I get a value of 0 because I transferred erc20 tokens and not eth  @shane

Comment: @strangethingspy I have updated the answer.

Comment: The problem is: how do I parse this using web3.py ?

Comment: The length of the parameters in the input data is a fixed number (in this case). There are 65 characters in each parameter. In this case, you can simply take the last 65 characters of the input data, search for the first non-zero number (from the left), and you will know that what remains is your value.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to add to the accepted answer, because I dislike parsing the input to some arbitrary length. What I found was that the actual hex value is also contained in the `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)` response.

If you inspect the response, there is a `logs[]` property, which for me always contains 1 object. This object has `data` property, which is excatly the hex value of the transaction. Example:

```
logs: [{
   "address": "0x905ed504db11Dd3b8C2bBe79E9A0A6c39E1A0deb",
   "blockNumber": 3262252,
   "data": "0xea"
}]
```

When i take this value I easily convert it to a number: `web3.utils.toBN('0xea')`