# How to derive value from transactions ETH

Tags: etherscan

When I use python web3 to get an transaction:

`w3.eth.getTransaction('0x0ae2e71023a5801e557472d9b58dee483a8617cff3afcdeae171889e0db70ded')`

I get:

```
AttributeDict({'blockHash': HexBytes('0x422914431295157e7b2560bd8f92fb49bc67c3c55f266904771ab860ecaa7bc8'), 'blockNumber': 13435586, 'from': '0x21a31Ee1afC51d94C2eFcCAa2092aD1028285549', 'gas': 207128, 'gasPrice': 112000000000, 'hash': HexBytes('0x0ae2e71023a5801e557472d9b58dee483a8617cff3afcdeae171889e0db70ded'), 'input': '0x', 'nonce': 1924466, 'r': HexBytes('0xc42909ca52009ba8d1b599e5677da00b37318a33a2037e447becc5c2b916dad0'), 's': HexBytes('0x4d476d7752f8e06f6ea1b975af01d3e0a74786262afd8f2f5621c0e81c4e946d'), 'to': '0xc2Cf260adb36Be2f45dC491457a30D6FbeD55E51', 'transactionIndex': 71, 'type': '0x0', 'v': 37, 'value': 780647230000000000})
```

When I go on etherscan I get a lot more information. Most importantly, the `value` field on etherscan tells me how much this transaction transferred (0.78064723 Ether).

`https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0ae2e71023a5801e557472d9b58dee483a8617cff3afcdeae171889e0db70ded`

I read on this forum you may potentially be able to extract that information from the `input`. ([here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/68601/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-transaction)) but my input is `0x`...? what does that mean? how can I get the `value` field like etherscan?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this response you also get the ETH transfered it is the last key - `'value': 780647230000000000`. Here is the value of the transaction represented in `WEI`.

`1 ETH = 1*10^18 WEI = 1,000,000,000,000,000,000 WEI` 
`780647230000000000 WEI = 0,78064723 ETH`

Comment: right, thanks. so I have another transaction: "0x42d6b283c36150475c75edd67ca3ee76cd8eef863b8d8bfcec836f04c27195b5" and this one has value = 0. whats the difference between these transactions?

Comment: The first send ETH somewhare, the second does not. Don't forget to upvote :)